# How to define if a determinate point is inside a region lat, long?

Tags: java

I have a region defined by a set List of geopoints and I need to know if a coordinate is inside this region

```
public class Region{
    List<Coordinate> boundary;

}

public class Coordinate{

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

}

public static boolean isInsideRegion(Region region, Coordinate coordinate){


}
```

Comment: I'm doing this just processing data from a database, so I'm not processing this from google maps or bing maps api

Comment: What's a `Region`? What's a `Coordinate`. We can't answer unless we tell us what these classes are

Comment: A coordinate is a point that has a latitude and longitude value like a map coordinate a region is on the map that is marked by a set of geopoints

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can apply a [Point in polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) algorithm from the [Computational Geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_geometry) set of problems.

There are four algorithms written in C by Paul Bourke, you can see the code [here](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/insidepoly/). There is an adaptation to Java in a [Processing Forum](http://forum.processing.org/topic/how-do-i-find-if-a-point-is-inside-a-complex-polygon), just in case you can't use Java7:

```
public class RegionUtil {

    boolean coordinateInRegion(Region region, Coordinate coord) {
        int i, j;
        boolean isInside = false;
        //create an array of coordinates from the region boundary list
        Coordinate[] verts = (Coordinate)region.getBoundary().toArray(new Coordinate[region.size()]);
        int sides = verts.length;
        for (i = 0, j = sides - 1; i < sides; j = i++) {
            //verifying if your coordinate is inside your region
            if (
                (
                 (
                  (verts[i].getLongitude() <= coord.getLongitude()) && (coord.getLongitude() < verts[j].getLongitude())
                 ) || (
                  (verts[j].getLongitude() <= coord.getLongitude()) && (coord.getLongitude() < verts[i].getLongitude())
                 )
                ) &&
                (coord.getLatitude() < (verts[j].getLatitude() - verts[i].getLatitude()) * (coord.getLongitude() - verts[i].getLongitude()) / (verts[j].getLongitude() - verts[i].getLongitude()) + verts[i].getLatitude())
               ) {
                isInside = !isInside;
            }
        }
        return isInside;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luigi But in my case I get an object with a list of latitudes and longitudes I cant figure out what are the vertices of the shape from code? how can I figure what are the vertices from those coordinates?

Comment: if it's a circular? i have a "radius":375, and "center":[116.31179,39.987505],the method can't located

Comment: @user2245634 this algorithm doesn't apply for your problem, starting with the diferrence between a polygon and a circular region. Still, you can do it in 3 steps: 1) trace an imaginary line between your center and the given point, 2) calculate the points where this imaginary line cross your circle using the center and the radius, 3) check if your point is between these 2 points (the three are already in the same imaginary line). If you have more specific questions about it, post your own question and show your attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: (coord.y - verts[i].getLongitude()) ,coord.y is what ?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Path2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html) to construct the region boundary shape. Then, create an [`Area`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html) using the `Path2D` and you can query `contains` quickly to determine whether your points are contained in the area. :-)

```
/* assuming a non-zero winding rule */
final Path2D boundary = new Path2D.Double();
/* initialize the boundary using moveTo, lineTo, quadTo, etc. */
final Area area = new Area(boundary);
...
/* test for whether a point is inside */
if (area.contains(...)) {
  ...
}
```

Note: there is little reason to roll your own `Region` and `Coordinate` classes for what the Java geometry classes provide. I suggest you abandon `Coordinate` (which is technically a misnomer as it's actually a *pair* of graticular coordinates) in favor of `Point2D`.

---

Note that there *is* a [`Polygon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) class, though it is tailored towards actual use for graphics and a relic of the past. It only supports `int` coordinates, which likely won't do you any good when using geopoints!

Comment: Path2D already has a contains() method.  Is there an advantage to creating the Area?  Otherwise a good answer (you beat me to it by a minute).  +1

Comment: I suggested he use `Area` since it just seemed more specially tuned towards areas (vs shapes) and supports operations like addition/difference :-)